# Is there any command to get process name+no of instance running in box except for Java process

Tags: shell

I am trying to get a list of processes ("agents" in sterling terminology) running is agent box along with their no. of instances e.g

```
process_name~no. of instance
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, in its current form your answer is not quite understandable. Please edit your question to include the following information: what OS flavour and version are you using? What do you mean with "agent box". What have you already tried, and where did you encounter problems? What are the requirements on the formatting of the output?

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
ps -ef | grep <your process name> | wc -l
```

`ps -ef` gets all processes, `grep` fetches the process that you are looking for, `wc -l` counts the number of instances found.

**EDIT**

As Devilan mentioned, the processes can be of single letter, you can use the below command for that.

```
~# ps -C a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5122 pts/1    00:00:00 a
 6232 pts/1    00:00:00 a
```

`-C` stands for command, pass your process name and it will list all the processes in that name.Use `wc -l` to count them.

Comment: What if process is named simply with one letter like `a`?

Comment: @DevilaN, didn't think about that. Will update the answer.